# XAMPP Mac MYSQL Error (MySQL PID Not Found)

Tags: mysql, macos, xampp

When I try to start my MYSQL server on XAMPP and a Mac computer.
I use this command to try and start it:

`/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/share/mysql/mysql.server force-reload`

and after i use it i get this error  `ERROR! MySQL PID file could not be found!`

im also using osx lion if that helps

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed this by restarting my own computer.